# jquery onsubmit doesn't work

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, submit, confirm

I have a form

```
    <form id="formModLezione" method="post">
```

now, I'm trying to do this:

```
 var messaggio="";
 var url = "EsistonoIscritti";
 var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
 xmlHttp.open("POST", url, false);
 xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
 xmlHttp.send("id="+id);
 xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4) // COMPLETED
{   if (xmlHttp.status == 200) // SUCCESSFUL
        {var str = xmlHttp.responseText;
         if (str.localeCompare("ko") != 0) {//ci sono utenti iscritti
             var utenti=JSON.parse(str);
             messaggio+="A questa lezione sono iscritte le seguenti persone, avvertile!\n";
      for(var i=0;i<utenti.length;i++){
        messaggio+=(i+1)+") "+utenti[i].nome+" "+utenti[i].cognome+" Tel."+utenti[i].telefono+"\n";
      }
        messaggio+="Vuoi procedere?";
        alert("messaggio");
         }
    } else {
        alert("An error occurred while communicating with the server.");
            }
    }
};
$("#formModLezione").on("submit","return confirm('"+messaggio+"');");
$("#formModLezione").attr("action","ModificaLezione?id="+id);
```

When I click on the submit button of the form the call to the servlet ModificaUtente works but doesn't show me any alert!
Someone know why?
thanks!

Comment: if you are using jquery, why don't you use the inbuilt `ajax()` function?

Comment: @martincarlin87 I'm using ajax call only to build the variable messaggio. Ok, I have to use the ajax function but it would not work so well?

Comment: no, it's just that it's probably far easier using the jquery function rather than doing it the old way which you are using just now.

Comment: @martincarlin87 the problem however is the onsubmit, not the ajax call.

Comment: yeah, I just find it easier to debug is all. Your url looks strange to me, shouldn't `EsistonoIscritti` be some sort of script, e.g. `esistonoiscritti.php`? Also, what version of jQuery are you using? I think `on` is only for jQuery > 1.7. Any errors in your console?

Comment: @martincarlin87 EsistonoIscritti is a java servlet and I'm using jquery 1.8.
But I've tried also with .submit() and with .bind() and does not word..

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that there is a syntax problem, but something like this maybe?

```
$("#formModLezione").on("submit", function(){
    confirm(messagio);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$("#formModLezione").bind("submit", function(e){
   e.preventDefault();

    confirm(messagio);
});
```